# jQuery: on change get closest element?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying to use jquery to get the closest element to an input field so I can use the element's text/html as the value of the input field.

my jquery looks like this:

```
<script>
jQuery("[name=currencies]").val(Currency.currentCurrency).change(function() {

 $(".moneyPrice").val($(this).closest('.mypro').find($("span.money").text()));

});
</script>
```

the `span.money` is being created dynamically.

and my HTML looks like this:

```
<div align="center" class="mypro" style="position:relative; width:270px; height:570px; border:solid 1px #CCC; margin:10px; float:left; overflow:hidden; padding:5px;">

<a class="overlay" href="product.php"></a>

<!--<a class="overlayBtns" href="">Quick View</a>-->

<a class="overlayAdd" href="javascript:{}" onclick="form'.$id.'.submit();"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
Add To Basket</a>


<img width="100%" src="product_images/'.$id.'Image1.jpg" alt=""  />


<p style="padding:2px;">'.$product_name.'</p>
<p style="padding:2px;">'.$manu.'</p>

    <div style="padding:5px;" class="price">

      <div class="prod-price"><span class=money>£'.$price.'.00</span></div>

        <form id="form'.$id.'" name="form1" method="post" action="cart.php">
        <input type="hidden" name="pid" id="pid" value="'.$id.'" />
        <input type="text" name="" class="moneyPrice" value="" />
      </form>   
    </div>

</div>
```

the HTML code above also, created `dynamically` using PHP.

so basically, when the select option changes, my jquery code fires up. But I get this in my input field `[object object]`.

if I change my jquery code to this:

```
$(".moneyPrice").val($("span.money").text());
```

it will display the `span.money` text in my input fields but the issue is that it will display ALL of the dynamically created span.money texts in all the input fields.

So for that reason, I need to get the closest `span.money`, to `.moneyPrice` input field and then display the span.money into the closest `.moneyPrice` input field.

Sorry if this is a bit confusing and I hope I get some help from yo guys.

any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

```
<select id="currencies" name="currencies">


   <option value="GBP" selected="selected">GBP</option>
  <option value="USD" >USD</option>


    <option value="NGN">NGN</option>







    <!--<option value="AUD">AUD</option>



    <option value="SGD">SGD</option>-->



    <option value="EUR">EUR</option>


</select>
```

EDIT:

i have created a working jsfiddle so you can see the issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/v6v146sv/

Comment: Sorry I am not seeing `name=currencies` in the code? Sorry if I too am missing something here in the code or have overlooked it.

Comment: would you be able to reformat this so all of the HTML is as you have it in your file?

Comment: How exactly do you create the span.money elements?

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax isn't quite right , likely as a result of trying to do too much in one line

```
$(".moneyPrice").val($(this).closest('.mypro').find($("span.money").text()));
```

Should be

```
$(".moneyPrice").val($(this).closest('.mypro').find("span.money").text());
```

Note that your find() would be the same as

```
var txt = $("span.money").text();// is not a selector
find(txt) // returns jQuery object not a text value but `txt` isn't a valid selector either
```

Comment: Your code doesn't put anything in my input fields at all!

Comment: Then provide a proper html representation of this issue. A demo in jsfiddle.net would help. We can't help with tarverses if you don't show the proper tree structure

Comment: WHere does the select fit into the page with relation to `mypro`? If it's not inside `mypro` then `closest()` won't work

Comment: Thanks again for the reply. the select is not inside the mypro. the select is actually outside of mypro and it is inside its own separate div. I was gonna create a jsfiddle but I have so many codes which makes it impossible to put it all in the jsfiddle. is there any chance I could come into a chat with you and share the link so you can see what's been done? OR what is the solution if the select is outside of the mypro?

Comment: Show the tree structure. Can get it from browser instead of copying from php code

Comment: the tree structure of HTML?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71949/discussion-between-tero-and-charlietfl).

Comment: Structure of html in a page is considered a `tree` structure. WIthout you showing relationship of select to the other elements is very hard to help any further

Comment: I have created a jsfiddle now which you can view here: http://jsfiddle.net/v6v146sv/

Comment: seems to be working to me. If you have new issues I suggest you start a new question and delete this one since this one is a bit of a mess

Comment: tried to delete it but it says I cannot because it has answers.

Answer (score 0):

**What you would have to do is to change**

```
$(".moneyPrice").val($(this).closest('.mypro').find($("span.money").text()));
```

to

```
$(".moneyPrice").val( $(this).closest('.mypro').find("span.money").text() );
```

I've also noticed some major errors in the html-code. When having variables in the html-code you would have to surrond them with "php start" and "php end".

Something like...

I want `<?php echo $nr_of_icecreams;?>` ice-creams

NOT

I want `$nr_of_icecreams` which seems what you're doing in your code

Comment: doesn't make sense to set value of `this` inside a change handler.

Comment: Haha of course. I didn't look at the html well enough. It would have made sense if there were more than one element with class moneyPrice, but in this case it doesn't. Thanks for noticing!